# Issue in fetching data from nested JSON file

Tags: android, json

I'm new to android. I have a JSON file with multiple arrays and I'm able to fetch data from the first array and display it in listview (check the first for loop). But i tried to fetch the next array and i didn't get any results(blank screen).  I need to display values from "open_days" array. Posted my JSON file and for loop portion.Please check and help me

MainActivity. java

```
try {
                    JSONObject jjsonObject =new JSONObject(result);
                    String getObject = jjsonObject.getString("message");
                    String getObject1 = jjsonObject.getString("status");

                    JSONArray getArray = jjsonObject.getJSONArray("favorite_facility_list");

                    Log.e("message",getObject);
                    Log.e("status",getObject1);

                    Log.e("favorite_facility_list",getArray.toString());

                    for(int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String promotion_id = objects.getString("facility_id");
                        String promotion_image_name = objects.getString("facility_course_name");
                        String promotion_image_url = objects.getString("icon_image_name");


                        JSONArray array2=jjsonObject.getJSONArray("open_days");
                        for(int j=0;j<array2.length();j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject obj2=array2.getJSONObject(j);
                            String openid = obj2.getString("open_days_id");
                            String openname = obj2.getString("open_days_name");
    //


                        promotionlists promotionlists = new promotionlists();
                        promotionlists.setFacility_id(promotion_id);
                        promotionlists.setFacility_course_name(promotion_image_name);
                        promotionlists.setIcon_image_name(promotion_image_url);
                            promotionlists.setOpen_days_id(openid);
                            promotionlists.setOpen_days_name(openname);

                        promotionArray.add(promotionlists);
                        adapter= new CustomAdapter(promotionArray,getApplicationContext());

                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }}
```

JSON file:

```
{
        "status": "1",
        "message": "Success",
        "favorite_facility_list": [
            {
                "facility_id": "11",
                "facility_course_name": "Facility 2",
                "icon_image_name": "3.jpg",
                "banner_image_name_list": [
                    "39.jpg"
                ],
                "address": "test1",
                "open_days": [
                    {
                        "open_days_id": "5",
                        "open_days_name": "Thursday"
                    },
                    {
                        "open_days_id": "6",
                        "open_days_name": "Friday"
                    },
                    {
                        "open_days_id": "8",
                        "open_days_name": "Sunday"
                    },
                    {
                        "open_days_id": "7",
                        "open_days_name": "Saturday"
                    }
                ],
                "open_time_start": "6:8 pm",
                "open_time_end": "12:8 pm",
                "workouts": [
                    {
                        "workout_id": "1",
                        "workout_name": "Aerobic"
                    },
                    {
                        "workout_id": "2",
                        "workout_name": "Yoga"
                    },
                    {
                        "workout_id": "4",
                        "workout_name": "Gym"
                    },
                    {
                        "workout_id": "8",
                        "workout_name": "Pool"
                    }
                ],
                "equipments": [
                    {
                        "equipment_id": "5",
                        "equipment_name": "Rowing"
                    },
                    {
                        "equipment_id": "6",
                        "equipment_name": "Stationary Bike"
                    },
                    {
                        "equipment_id": "7",
                        "equipment_name": "Bench Press"
                    },
                    {
                        "equipment_id": "8",
                        "equipment_name": "TRX"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    {
                        "service_id": "4",
                        "service_name": "Tranning"
                    },
                    {
                        "service_id": "1",
                        "service_name": "Personal Training"
                    }
                ],
                "drop_in_rate": [
                    "10-test",
                    "20-test1",
                    "30-test3"
                ],
                "parking_status": "1",
                "parking_notes": "2 hrs available",
                "facility_status": "1",
                "facility_status_description": "Live",
                "rating": "2.90",
                "distance": "9412.2ml",
                "already_like": 1,
                "weburl": "",
                "phone_no": "",
                "facility_lattitude": "-3",
                "facility_longitude": "151"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: what does your error says?

Comment: that's because your `jjsonObject` is your root json, and does not have `open_days`. You need to look for `open_days` in `objects`

Comment: use retrofit or volley or any other 3rd party library, to simplify this.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko: Thank u .. it worked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Logcat throws [**`JSONException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException).

**Don't**

```
JSONArray array2=jjsonObject.getJSONArray("open_days");
```

**Do**

```
  JSONArray array2=objects.getJSONArray("open_days");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong object to fetch `open_days`

Change

```
JSONArray array2 = jjsonObject.getJSONArray("open_days");
```

to

```
JSONArray array2 = objects.getJSONArray("open_days");
```